# Pandas to_csv is overwriting first row with header=

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .txt file that has a few thousand rows and 7 columns.  The file does not have a header, and starts with a row of values right away

| 100 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
| --- |
| 99 7 8 9 10 11 |

I read the file and convert it to a dataframe easy enough using pandas.  When converting the dataframe to a csv, I use

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="\t")
df1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=['a',"b","c","d","e","f","g"])
```

However when I open the CSV the first row (starting with 100) is replaced with

| a b c d e f g |
| --- |
| 99 7 8 9 10 11 |

instead of how i would **like** it to look:

| a, b, c, d, e, f, g |
| --- |
| 100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, |
| 99, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 |

using `df1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=None)` omits the first row all together and I end up with

| 99 7 8 9 10 11 |
| --- |
| 98 12 13 14 15 16 |

using `df1.iloc[0] = 0` just ends up making the first row the header, inserting [0] for index position 0, and I end up with this:

| 100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, |
| --- |
| 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, |
| 99, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 |

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you need to use `header=None` argument on `read_csv()`.  Otherwise it interprets the first row as a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df1)
df1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

I think you forgot to check if the file was read properly.

file.txt

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
```

file.csv

```
a,b,c
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the 'names=' in pandas for header rows.  But I added in my new column names and that worked - thank you!